# Add a character for every 3 characters for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsstring

I am trying to add a character while user is typing for every three characters, for example user types : `123456789` it should automatically change to `123,456,789`. How can I add character in

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Comment: What characters will be entered in your textfield? Is it only numbers?

Comment: @Adrian yes the entry is only numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way how to do that:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var proposedString = (textField.text as NSString?)!.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    // do whatever modifications you need to do, e.g. remove commas:
    proposedString = proposedString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
    let modulo = proposedString.count % 3
    for index in stride(from: modulo, to: proposedString.count, by: 3).reversed() {
        print(index)
        if index != 0 {
            proposedString.insert(",", at: proposedString.index(proposedString.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
        }
    }

    // manually set the new value
    textField.text = proposedString

    // don't let it update itself
    return false
}
```

**Note:** This little algorithm of mine works with commas only - you should therefore do adding the commas using `Locale` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html)), or `NumberFormatter` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)) if the commas are part of how you present number in your country.

Comment: @Mc.Lover well, from your question I assumed you want to react to every user's input, and format the number that has been inputed so that there will appear commas after every 3 digits.. If that's not the case, then you should update your question and specify the question in other words

Comment: @Mc.Lover oh, so the question is about the algorithm for the digits? I left a comment where you should implement that, because I assumed you have an algorithm for that.. didn't know you want us to do all the work for you

Comment: Oh! it's very nice of you. it works now sorry I am little novice

Comment: @Mc.Lover although this is hardocoded to work for commas, you should use `Locale` to parse numbers if the goal is to show those numbers in "pretty print"

Comment: @Mc.Lover Do not use this solution if your goal is to format numbers. Most places around the world use different ways to group large numbers and only showing groups of three digits with a comma will be very confusing to most of your users. The solution using `NumberFormatter` is the proper way to format a number for display to a user.

Comment: @rmaddy no , the textfield is only for my use. Its ok

Answer (score 1):

You should take into consideration that different regions across the world use different ways of formatting a number. To get around that fact, let iOS do the formatting for you.

This turns out to be exceptionally simple. The one line of code you require is:

```
NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: 123456 as NSNumber, number: NumberFormatter.Style.decimal)
```